# Azure policy to stop user from creating SAS token

Tags: azure-storage, azure-policy

i want to implement a policy where no user can create SAS token (irrespective of Role). except if belongs to a certain AD group.

I know I can set an option at storage account to completely stop SAS option, but i do not want to do that. I just want it to be done by one certain group.

I am not able to save this policy, i am getting error on "action" attribute. I am not sure, how to achieve it without action.

```
{
  "mode": "all",
  "description": "This policy prevents public access to Azure Storage accounts.",
  "parameters": {
    "allowedPrincipals": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "List of principal IDs that are allowed to regenerate SAS keys."
      }
    }
  },
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
        },
        {
            "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/allowSharedKeyAccess",
            "notEquals": true
   
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny",
      "actions": [
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/regenerateKey/action"
      ],
      "condition": {
        "not": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments[*].principalId",
          "in": "[parameters('allowedPrincipals')]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There’s a BIG difference between regenerating Storage Account Keys and generating SAS Tokens.

Storage Account Keys are the primary method by which the storage account is secured.  Changing either key would invalidate ALL SAS tokens generated using that key.

SAS Tokens can be generated offline by anyone who has a Storage Account Key.  Since it’s an offline operation, you can’t stop someone from doing it; however, you can stop them from being able to get the Storage Account Keys.

What you probably want to do is block everyone but a small group of people from reading the Storage Account Keys.  I’m afraid I’m not sure what the permission that equates to (but it is a distinct API call and I’m pretty sure it’s a separate permission).

Reference: [Prevent Shared Key authorization for an Azure Storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/shared-key-authorization-prevent?tabs=portal)

[Grant limited access to Azure Storage resources using shared access signatures (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview)

[Configure an expiration policy for shared access signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/sas-expiration-policy?tabs=azure-portal)